# spring rsocket response metadata

Tags: spring-rsocket

When using spring-boot-starter-rsocket is there a way to send response metadata from a MessageMapping-annotated method? I also don't see a way for RSocketRequester to receive metadata (all RSocketRequester.RetrieveSpec retrieveMethods seem to return the decoded response payload data, and have no way to return the response payload metadata).